# Spring Roo 1.3.1 release

Tags: spring, spring-roo, roo

I am new to the spring Roo. We are using spring Roo 1.3.1 in our project. I have roo aspect files like roo_javabean.aj(for setters and getters) and roo_jpaEntity.aj in my porject when i check out my project from svn. I was told whenever we add a new property to domain object we need to run roo command on the porject location in command line.

So i downloaded roo 2.0.0.M3 version as i couldn't find 1.3.1 release online. I added one property in my domain object and ran roo command on my command line hoping roo would update the roo_javabean.aj file with setters and getters of the new property variable(@Transient public Date oneTest;) i added, but roo is deleting my existing aspect files for my domain object. please see the below

> C:\Users\workspace\project>roo
>                   _
>    **_ _ __  _ __(*)* __   __ _   _ __**    
>   **/ __| '_ \| '**| | '_ \ / _` | | '**/ _ \ / _ \
>   __ \ |*) | |  | | | | | (*| | | | | (*) | (*) |
>   |**/ .**/||  |*|*| |*|_*, | |_|  _**/ ___/
>       |_|                 |___/           2.0.0.M3

Welcome to Spring Roo. For assistance press TAB or type "hint" then hit ENTER.
WARNING: You are using Spring Roo 2.0.0.M3, but project was generated using Spring Roo 1.3.1.RELEASE
.
If you continue with the execution your project might suffer some changes.
Do you want to continue opening Spring Roo Shell?(YES/No)yes---->if i say yes it is deleting the present files.

Deleted SRC_MAIN_JAVA\com\vik\pro\domain\reference\example_Roo_Jpa_Entity.aj - not require
r governor com.vik.pro.domain.reference.example

---

I am not sure why, is it because i am using roo 2.0 and my project pom.xml is defined as 1.3.1.

Is there any i can download 1.3.1 release because all I can find is 1.2.5, 1.3.2 and 2.0.0 in spring website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There're a big number of differences between Spring Roo 2.x and 1.x versions to be able to maintain the backward compatibility between them.

The following message appears when you use a different version of Spring Roo in a Spring Roo generated project.

```
WARNING: You are using Spring Roo 2.0.0.M3, but project was generated using Spring Roo 1.3.1.RELEASE . If you continue with the execution your project might suffer some changes. Do you want to continue opening Spring Roo Shell?(YES/No)
```

That confirmation message is really useful to prevent undesired changes in your project.

If you have just started to create your project, I recommed you that use Spring Roo 2.x version. It introduces the last Spring technologies (Spring IO, Spring Boot, Spring Data, etc.) in your project and generates a more flexible architecture (domain layer, repository layer, service layer and web layer with separated controllers and views)

However, you could download the Spring Roo 1.3.1 version from [here](http://spring-roo-repository.springsource.org.s3.amazonaws.com/release/ROO/spring-roo-1.3.1.RELEASE.zip)

Hope it helps,

Comment: I was able to run roo after downloading 1.3.1 version from the link you provided. I am not having any issues now. Roo is generating aspectJ files it is supposed to

Comment: Happy to hear that! :)